# unable to access objects of one class in another class in python

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to access the functions of class Config in another class. i am unable to do it. This code follows MVC structure.

i have tried putting that piece of code in another file and importing it and tried to use. No success.

```
class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.Data_load = ""
            self.MongoDB_Host = ""
        except:
            print("Not found")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('Config.ini')

    def getMongoDB_Host(self):
        return self.MongoDB_Host
    def getMongoDB_Port(self):
        return self.MongoDB_Port

class PredictionController(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.path = config.DEFAULT['pickle_path']

    def dev_train(self,df_dev):
        self.df_dev=df_dev
        Config_Obj = Config()
        print(Config_obj.getMongoDB_Host()) #This is giving output : response 51 bytes [200 OK]
```

Comment: how about adding Config_Obj.getMongoDB_Host()? under the last line of your example. Also, you do not need the ojbect superclass in PredictionController if you are not using python2. as you tagged the post with py3.x i think you dont need it.

Comment: am getting the following error: **<Response 51 bytes [200 OK]>** when i try to return the json object

Comment: 200 OK means it worked right? i dont really see the problem (https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)

Comment: am loading config.ini file in class Config and parsing it for the necessary values. when i am trying to access these values, its returning me with <Response 51 bytes [200 OK]> instead of actual values.

Comment: what are you using to parse the config. a library?

Comment: Yes. am using configparser library to parse the values.